# How to use sed command in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to execute the following bash script but it gives me invalid arithmetic operator error in line 8.

```
#!/bin/bash
criteria=$1
re_match=$2
replace=$3
for i in $( ls *$criteria* );
do
src=$i
tgt=$[echo $i | sed -e "s/$re_match/$replace/"]
mv $src $tgt
done
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: And [Bash Pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Comment: Especially pitfall #1. Also, when doing any sort of mass move or rename, you should *always* use `mv -n` or `mv -i` to prevent accidentally overwriting files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
$(echo $i | sed -e "s/$re_match/$replace/")
```

instead of

```
$[echo $i | sed -e "s/$re_match/$replace/"]
```

`$()` is used for variable expansion. `[]` is used for doing arithmetic.

Comment: As correct as the bit about bracket types might be, I can't upvote something that allows a script like the one in this question to go unchallenged. Your answer makes it seem as if `echo $i` is acceptable practice, and fails to challenge numerous other things that are in extreme need of correction. Please consider producing answers that contain *better code*, rather than just tell the OP how to get past whatever immediate problem their random keyboard bashing has gotten them into.